# Как в VS 2017 создать элемент диаграмма классов? C#

Tags: c#, ооп

Создаю Консольное приложение(.NET Framework). Далее выбираю функцию "Создать элемент". В открывающемся списке нет "диаграмм классов", которые мне необходимы, хотя во всех инструкциях, которые я смотрел - есть. Возможно у менять не установлены какие-то дополнительные компоненты для Visual Studio, но я не знаю, какие нужны. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Делаешь так?
Правый клик на проекте>Add>New item> ClassDiagram

Comment: У меня русский язык стоит, тем не менее нажимаю правой кнопкой мыши на проект. Добавить->Новый элемент... А диаграммы классов там нет.

Comment: а поиск там есть сверху справа?Там пробовали искать?

Comment: Нажми правой ПКМ на проект и выбери "Перейти к схеме классов"

Answer (score 7):

По умолчанию этот компонент не устанавливается в VS 2017. Для установки открываем VS Installer и у установленного экземпляра VS выбираем пункт "Изменить":

> [image: vs installer]

В открывшемся окне переходим на вкладку "Отдельные компоненты" и в разделе "Средства для работы с кодом" выбираем компонент "Конструктор классов" и устанавливаем его.

> [image: class designer]

После установки компонента элемент "Диаграмма классов" становится доступен.

**Альтернативный вариант**

В VS 2017 нажимаем комбинацию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> или в панели быстрого запуска (верхний правый угол) пишем "Конструктор классов" и выбираем появившийся элемент:

> [image: quick launch]

В открывшемся окне выбираем "Установить":

> [image: install class designer]

Связанная статья на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233831/class-diagrams-in-vs-2017